# I can not communicate with a data logger via modbus

Tags: java, serial-port, modbus

I'm trying to interface to a data logger like this:

[image]

I can send a question via serial, which is nothing more than an array of bytes. The problem is that I can not get an answer. I know the data logger communicates at 9600 baud. I tried to connect an oscilloscope to see if it could be a program or hardware problem, but the oscilloscope seems to send me an answer, but I'm not able to receive. This means that the problem is definitely the software. Below I show the answer in the oscilloscope

[image]

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SerialRead implements SerialPortEventListener
{

    private SerialPort serialPort;
    private static String st;
    private String PORT_ID;
    private static SerialRead mInstance = null;
    private InputStream input;
    private OutputStream output;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;

    //TODO: inserisci il baud per la velocità di acquisizione
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;


    public static SerialRead getInstance()
    {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SerialRead();
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * setto il valore della PORT_ID e vado a restituire l'istanza della classe
     * @param PORT_ID
     * @return
     */
    public SerialRead setPORT_ID(String PORT_ID) {
        this.PORT_ID = PORT_ID;

        if (PORT_ID == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Devi dare un valore alla porta");
        }

        return this;
    }


    private SerialRead() {
        //costruttore interno
        initialize();
        close();
    }


    /**
     * metodo che va a settare i parametri per l'inizializzazione della porta seriale ed
     * per la comunicazione seriale per gestire sucessivamente la richiesta con un
     * InputStream e OutputSteam
     * @return
     */
    public SerialRead initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        // iterate through, looking for the port
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(PORT_ID)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                System.out.println("-Porta connessa da " + SerialRead.class.getSimpleName());
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(PORT_ID, TIME_OUT);
            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            input = serialPort.getInputStream();
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * chiude la porta seriale così da liberare la comunicazione per la scrittura o la lettura
     * questo perchè è monodirezionale
     */
    private synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Richiamo il metodo definito all'interno dell'interfaccia implementata SerialPortEventListener
     * Creo un thread continuo per la lettura dei dati che andrà a terminare alla lettura di un dato specifico
     * Andremo a leggere i dati solamente nel caso in cui siano disponibili
     * @param oEvent
     */

    @Override
    public synchronized void serialEvent(final SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                    try {
                        int available = input.available();
                        byte[] chunk = new byte[available];
                        //System.out.println(chunk);
                        input.read(chunk, 0, available);
                        st = new String(chunk);
                        System.out.print(st);
                        /*try{ //impostato per risparmiare prestazioni e eseguire il ciclo meno spesso
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }*/
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

the SerialWriter.java

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SerialWriter
{

    /**
     * inizializzazione porte e strumenti per la scrittura della seriale
     */
    private SerialPort serialPort;
    private String PORT_ID;
    private static SerialWriter mInstance = null;
    private CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    private InputStream input;
    private OutputStream output;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;

    //TODO: inserisci il baud per la velocità di acquisizione
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    private SerialWriter() {
        //costruttore interno
        close();
    }


    public static SerialWriter getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SerialWriter();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * setto il valore della PORT_ID e vado a restituire l'istanza della classe
     * @param PORT_ID
     * @return
     */
    public SerialWriter setPORT_ID(String PORT_ID) {
        this.PORT_ID = PORT_ID;

        if (PORT_ID == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Devi dare un valore alla porta");
        }
        return this;
    }


    /**
     * metodo che va a settare i parametri per l'inizializzazione della porta seriale ed
     * per la comunicazione seriale per gestire sucessivamente la richiesta con un
     * InputStream e OutputSteam
     * @return
     */
    public SerialWriter initialize() {
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        // iterate through, looking for the port
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            //for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(PORT_ID)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    System.out.println("-Porta connessa da " + SerialWriter.class.getSimpleName());
                    break;
                }
           //}
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("scanner is not connected !");
        }
        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(PORT_ID, TIME_OUT);
            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            input = serialPort.getInputStream();
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * chiude la porta seriale così da liberare la comunicazione per la scrittura o la lettura
     * questo perchè è monodirezionale
     */
    private synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
            System.out.println("-Porta chiusa da " + SerialWriter.class.getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    /**
     * metodo create per inviare una serie ("infinita") di messaggi tramite il parametro varags(un array di elementi)
     * @param messagge
     */
    public void sendData(String... messagge) {

        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {

            OutputStream outstream = null;
            try {
                outstream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                for (String currentMessage: messagge) {
                    //TODO: da cancellare- solo per debugging 1-2 riga
                    System.out.println(currentMessage);
                    outstream.write("\n".getBytes());
                    outstream.write(currentMessage.getBytes());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        close();
    }


    public synchronized void sendData(byte... messagge) {

        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {

            OutputStream outstream = null;
            try {
                outstream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                /*for (byte currentMessage: messagge) {
                    //TODO: da cancellare- solo per debugging 1-2 riga
                    System.out.println(currentMessage);
                    //outstream.write("\n".getBytes());
                    outstream.write(currentMessage);
                    outstream.flush();
                }*/

                outstream.write(messagge);
                //outstream.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        close();
    }


    public void sendData(char... messagge) {

        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {

            OutputStream outstream = null;
            try {
                outstream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                for (char currentMessage: messagge) {
                    //TODO: da cancellare- solo per debugging 1-2 riga
                    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(currentMessage));
                    //outstream.write("\n".getBytes());
                    outstream.write(String.valueOf(currentMessage).getBytes());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        close();
    }

}
```

and the main activity:

```
public class SerialeEsegui
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String PORT_ID = "COM4";
        SerialRead.getInstance().setPORT_ID(PORT_ID).initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is no request sent so i assume this device is transmitting on its own. The Modbus protocol is by far more complicated than a standard serial communication. One usually needs to build something like a protocol stack in order to receives messages. We do a lot with Modbus and we are using the SuperCom library ([adontec.com](http://adontec.com)) for doing this. It also offers a function called RS_RXMODBUS that can receive raw Modbus data. Unfortunately this library is not free but works very reliable.

Comment: I solved the problem. It seems that the error was that every time I called the SerialeRead.java class after the SerialWriter.java class, the current serial channel was closed, that is writing, and then reopened it for reading. This caused a great deal of time that did not allow me to read the answer in time. I solved the problem by putting everything in one class. Unfortunately I could not import any bookshop because working in alternating school-work (high school) I can not buy bookstores. Thanks anyway for the advice

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is on the `close()` method which closes the serial and then reopens it. You have in fact created two classes for the serial that open and close, respectively in writing and reading (SerialWriting.java and SerialReading.java). But this makes no sense, in fact, creating a single class is all more correct and simple. It initializes the serial one time only and then you can manage the reading and writing of data directly inside it. The problem seems to be that you spend too much time changing from one class to another, and then close the serial port and then reopen it, thus losing the response of the data logger shown in the oscilloscope. In the code below, everything is managed by a single class and you can call the `close()` method when you have finished reading the data.

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

public class SerialManager implements SerialPortEventListener
{

    /**
     * inizializzazione porte e strumenti per la scrittura della seriale
     */
    private SerialPort serialPort;
    private String PORT_ID;
    private static String st;
    private static SerialManager mInstance = null;
    private CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    private InputStream input;
    private OutputStream output;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;


    //TODO: inserisci il baud per la velocità di acquisizione
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    private SerialManager() {
        //costruttore interno
        close();
    }


    public static SerialManager getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SerialManager();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * setto il valore della PORT_ID e vado a restituire l'istanza della classe
     * @param PORT_ID
     * @return
     */
    public SerialManager setPORT_ID(String PORT_ID) {
        this.PORT_ID = PORT_ID;

        if (PORT_ID == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Devi dare un valore alla porta");
        }
        return this;
    }


    /**
     * metodo che va a settare i parametri per l'inizializzazione della porta seriale ed
     * per la comunicazione seriale per gestire sucessivamente la richiesta con un
     * InputStream e OutputSteam
     * @return
     */
    public SerialManager initialize() {
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        // iterate through, looking for the port
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            //for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(PORT_ID)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                System.out.println("-Porta connessa da " + SerialManager.class.getSimpleName());
                break;
            }
            //}
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("scanner is not connected !");
        }
        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(PORT_ID, TIME_OUT);
            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            input = serialPort.getInputStream();
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * chiude la porta seriale così da liberare la comunicazione per la scrittura o la lettura
     * questo perchè è monodirezionale
     */
    private synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
            System.out.println("\n-Porta chiusa da " + SerialManager.class.getSimpleName());
        }
    }


    public synchronized void sendData(byte... messagge) {

        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {

            OutputStream outstream = null;
            try {
                outstream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                outstream.write(messagge);
                //outstream.flush();

                for (byte m : messagge) {
                    System.out.print(m + " ");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //close();
        try {
            System.out.println("\nSeriale in ascolto (in esadecimale)");
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void serialEvent(final SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                    try {
                        int available = input.available();
                        byte[] chunk = new byte[available];
                        input.read(chunk, 0, available);

                        for (byte b : chunk) {
                            builder.append(b).append(" ");
                        }

                        System.out.print(builder.toString());
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

and main activity:

```
public class SerialeEsegui
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String PORT_ID = "COM4";
        int b =  unsignedToBytes((byte) 0x93);
        int c =  unsignedToBytes((byte) 0xf4);
        int f =  unsignedToBytes((byte) 0xfd);
        int z =  unsignedToBytes((byte) 0xf1);

        //Request example
        byte array[] = new byte[]{0x01, 0x03, 0x00,(byte) b, 0x00, 0x0b, (byte) c, 0x20};
        byte array1[] = new byte[]{0x01, 0x10, 0x00,(byte) b, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x16, 0x23,
                0x40, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02,
                0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, (byte) f, (byte) z};

        SerialManager.getInstance().setPORT_ID(PORT_ID).initialize().sendData(array);
    }

    public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
        return b & 0xFF;
    }
}
```